# How to get SKU from Configure Product Custom Option?

Tags: magento2, php

I am trying to get custom option value (SKU) from Configure product custom option

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal):
               foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
                     // echo //$valuesVal->getId().' '.$valuesVal->getTitle();
                     //print_r($valuesVal->getData());
                     echo $valuesVal->getSku();
                }
endforeach;
```

but i can't get SKU..

Please assist me.

Comment: check this link - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-get-product-options-in-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code as below

**From:**

```
echo $valuesVal->getSKU();
```

**To:**

```
echo $valuesVal->getSku();
```

Comment: not get anything .. blank

Comment: What are you getting when write print_r($valuesVal->getData());?

Comment: I added new Filed in Custom option and get value, Thank You.